# Delete columns with several zeros

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I need to remove all columns with more than 1 zero. I am currently using `df <- df[, colSums(df != 0) > 1]` but this does not work for all of the columns with many zeros. How can this be fixed or approached a different way?

```
> tibble(df)
# A tibble: 551 x 1,046
            `aa`           `ab`           `ac`         `ad`         `ae`         `af` 
            <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        
 1          32458          65068          32654        0            43115         1450         
 2          19387          38457          19447        0            22523          958         
 3          42690          85105          43247        0            14156         1088         
 4          62290         123325          61878        58422        36300         1145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `select` to select columns where the `mean` of the logical expression i.e those elements that are 0 are less than 0.7

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(~ mean(. %in% 0) < 0.7))
```

-output

```
    aa     ab    ac    ae   af
1 32458  65068 32654 43115 1450
2 19387  38457 19447 22523  958
3 42690  85105 43247 14156 1088
4 62290 123325 61878 36300 1145
```

If it is to remove columns with more than 1 zero value

```
df %>%
   select(where( ~sum(. %in% 0) < 2))
```

-output

```
   aa     ab    ac    ae   af
1 32458  65068 32654 43115 1450
2 19387  38457 19447 22523  958
3 42690  85105 43247 14156 1088
4 62290 123325 61878 36300 1145
```

---

Or a similar option in `base R`

```
 Filter(function(x) mean(x %in% 0) < 0.7, df)
     aa     ab    ac    ae   af
1 32458  65068 32654 43115 1450
2 19387  38457 19447 22523  958
3 42690  85105 43247 14156 1088
4 62290 123325 61878 36300 1145
```

or using `sum` for count of zeros

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x %in% 0) < 2, df)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(aa = c(32458L, 19387L, 42690L, 62290L), ab = c(65068L, 
38457L, 85105L, 123325L), ac = c(32654L, 19447L, 43247L, 61878L
), ad = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 58422L), ae = c(43115L, 22523L, 14156L, 
36300L), af = c(1450L, 958L, 1088L, 1145L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: my goal is to just remove the columns with more than 1 zero, but I tried the above and it is not working

Comment: @aurelius_37809 but your description says 70% 0

Comment: sorry if that was misleading I was just describing the characteristics of `df`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try `colMeans` like below

```
df[colMeans(df == 0) < 0.7]
```